# How to get access token using OAuth 2.0 in PayPal java SDK?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I saw PayPal REST request documentation for java SDK at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/.

It requires a developer to register an application.
Now, using the calls mentioned by using the clientId and secret, i can receive an access token. This access token will belong to me and not any other user, so i will only be able to access my resources.
Now, If i make an application, and want to obtain access token of the user using my application, how can the SDK be used to achieve this workflow?

Answer (score -2):

We recently created the instructions to use PayPal Java SDK. You can read them about it here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call

Using Java-SDK, you do not need to create access token separately. Instead you create an `APIContext` object, and pass your clientId, secret, and mode(sandbox/live). You pass this instance to all the API operations, and SDK will automatically call the oauth, and get the access token. This also improves performance by caching the access token and re-using it for later use. This only should reduce number of network calls to half.